# Can we calculate leakage power after synthesis at the architectural level power analysis itself?

Tags: vlsi, vivado, processor, mips

As I understand it, leakage power depends after implementation and not on the architectural level itself.

When I report power after synthesis in Vivado I get even the leakage power. Is this possible or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: It will be an estimation, probably.

Comment: *I get even the leakage power* So, you get it, but you're asking whether it's possible? Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I meant "get" in the vivado tool .the leakage current which is displayed shouldn't have been there ,since it is architectural level analysis only the dynamic power should have been present so what is the leakage power that is being displayed